# How to pass a PHP array to another PHP page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been looking for this answer without success.
I have three files: index.php, actions.js and devices.php

My index.php have this code:

```
<?php
        $file = "canvas/interactiveWorkstations/".$roomData['id'].".json";
        if(file_exists($file)){
            $map = "interactiveWorkstation";
            $lines = file($file);
            $nPolygon = $lines[count($lines) - 4];
            $counterPolygon = 0;
            $pos = 4;
            $areas = array();

            while($counterPolygon !== $nPolygon && $pos < count($lines)){
                $lines[$pos] = json_decode($lines[$pos], true);
                if($counterPolygon !== 0)
                    $lines[$pos] = array_diff_assoc($lines[$pos], $lines[$pos-9]);
                $coords = "";
                foreach($lines[$pos] as $line)
                    foreach($line as $k => $v)
                        if($k !== "color" && $v !== -1)
                            $coords .= $v . ", ";
                $coords = trim($coords, ', '); //Delete last space and last comma
                $lines[$pos-3] = trim($lines[$pos-3], '#');
                $areas[trim($lines[$pos-3])] = $coords;
                $counterPolygon++;
                $pos = $pos + 9;
            }
    ?>
        <script>
            var img = document.getElementsByClassName('connection')[0];
            img.setAttribute('usemap', '<?php echo "#".$map; ?>');
            img.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<map name="<?php echo $map; ?>" id="<?php echo $map; ?>"></map>');
            var points = <?php echo json_encode($areas);?>;
        </script>
    <?php
        }
       if($bookingActive) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">reloadDevices("'.$workstationName.'","'.$randomKey.'","'.$bookingData['ical_uid'].'",points); initCountdown('.$remainingTime.');</script>';
}
```

At this point I have passed my $areas variable to JS using json_encode, and my functions reloadDevices() and UpdateDevices() receive it correctly because I checked before.

In my actions.js file have this code:

```
function updateDevices(workstation,randomKey,z,points){
    var parameters = {
            "workstation" : workstation,
            "randomKey" : randomKey,
            "z" : z,
            "points" : points
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parameters,
            url:   'workstation/devices.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function (response) {
                    $("#devices").html(response);
            }
    });
}
function reloadDevices(workstation,randomKey,z,points) {
    updateDevices(workstation,randomKey,z, points);
    setInterval(function () { updateDevices(workstation,randomKey,z, points); }, 6000);
}
```

I do an ajax call to devices.php, but when I wanna get my $_POST['points'] variable is empty.
The part of code from my devices.php where I use this variable:

```
<?php
$areas = json_decode($_POST['points'], true);
?>
<script>
    var map = document.getElementById('interactiveWorkstation');
    var area = document.getElementById('<?php echo $deviceName; ?>');
    if(!area)
        map.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<area id="<?php echo $deviceName; ?>" shape="polygon" coords="<?php echo $areas[$deviceName]; ?>" href=\'javascript:createTerminal(<?php echo "\"".$deviceName."\""; ?>, <?php echo "\"".$deviceIp; ?>-<?php echo $randomKey."\""; ?>, <?php echo "\"".$uid."\""; ?>, <?php echo "\"".$deviceName."\""; ?>);\'/>');
</script>
```

Honestly, I can't see the error. If someone helps me appreciate it.
Thanks so much.
Regards.

Comment: Try to var_dump the $_POST to see what variables it brings. In your device.php file.

Comment: var_dump print:
array(4) { ["workstation"]=> string(16) "workstation-test" ["randomKey"]=> string(32) "ed39c565109d0328f318d318546ea37e" ["z"]=> string(44) "MRBS-570e4b9dec760-aa7dc847@serverlab.uhu.es" ["points"]=> array(3) { ["R1Gtest"]=> string(78) "29, 42, 47, 37, 65, 34, 82, 39, 90, 53, 86, 67, 78, 75, 61, 76, 43, 74, 31, 67" ["R2Gtest"]=> string(70) "151, 41, 173, 34, 195, 38, 207, 48, 209, 64, 190, 74, 170, 73, 153, 66" ["S1Gtest"]=> string(132) "29, 42, 47, 37, 65, 34, 82, 39, 90, 53, 86, 67, 78, 75, 61, 76, 43, 74, 31, 67, 42, 116, 91, 117, 92, 134, 77, 153, 22, 153, 25, 136" } }

Comment: `["points"]=> array(3)` it's obviously not empty

Comment: ok, now try to var_dump the $_POST['points'] and the $areas variable. Should be related to json_decode result. By the way, that's the problem when you merge everything in one file JavaScript, PHP and HTML. Will be good since you have a .php file and a .js file maintain the code where they belong. Is going to be easier for you to debug.

Comment: var_dump the $_POST['points'] has the datas.
var_dump the $areas is NULL.

Comment: Great, now you see why is not working. Your call to the json_decode function here is not returning anything.

Comment: change it to $areas = $_POST['points'] and evaluate that variable to see how are you going to get the value you need. If it is an array should  be as simple as $areas['R1Gtest'].

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): "NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit."

Comment: Ok all works now. This project is a monitoring of workstations in real time, so I can't do it in other way. It's a modification of another project, so I have to adjust myself to the code that already exists. Sorry for the issues and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Perfect! no problem, keep coding!